# How can I check if player is an operator in Forge?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

In Minecraft Forge, I would like to know if there is any way to find out if a player currently has vanilla "OP" / "Operator" status. I can't find a method that does this on the EntityPlayer Class.

I'd like something like:

```
EntityPlayer player = (EntityPlayer)sender;
if (player.getOpStatus) {
    [do some stuff]
}
```

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic and [not suitable for this site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for MinecraftForge documentation

Comment: @Rouze [Mod questions are allowed](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here). I removed the documentation question, since that is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Using `EntityPlayerMP#canCommandSenderUseCommand(int permLevel, String commandName)` might be a way to find out if a player is an operator.